# Rewrite URL iis 7 - https://www.somewhere.com -> https://somewhere.com

Tags: ssl, iis-7, url-rewriting, ssl-certificate, url-rewrite-module

I'm trying to redirect my site from WWW -> root.

http://www.example.com -> http://example.com 
https://www.example.com -> https://example.com

i've used the following rewrite rules:

```
<rule name="CanonicalHostNameHttp" stopProcessing="true">
<match url="(.*)" />  
<conditions logicalGrouping="MatchAll" trackAllCaptures="false">
<add input="{HTTP_HOST}" pattern="^example\.com$" negate="true" />
<add input="{HTTPS}" pattern="^OFF$" />
</conditions>
<action type="Redirect" url="http://example.com/{R:1}" />
</rule>

<rule name="Redirect to HTTPS" enabled="true" stopProcessing="true">
<match url="(.*)" />
<conditions logicalGrouping="MatchAll" trackAllCaptures="false">
<add input="{HTTPS}" pattern="^OFF$" />
</conditions>
<action type="Redirect" url="https://{HTTP_HOST}/{R:1}" redirectType="Permanent" />
</rule>
```

This works fine:

- I enter http://www.example.com, it redirects to http://example.com
- http://example.com then redirects to https://example.com

**This fails:**

- I enter **https://www.example.com**
- It never redirects to https://example.com
- And as a result it gives me a certificate error (because my certificate is for example.com not www.example.com)

What am I missing???

Answer (score 1):

How about buying a cheap cert for www.example.com as mentioned here... [invalid security certificate and domain names](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/449212/invalid-security-certificate-and-domain-names)
...and then set up a rule to redirect https://www.example.com -> https://example.com?

I have a similar problem at the moment. The problem is I can't install a second cert because Amazon EC2 limits you to a single public IP address per instance, and an IP address can only be bound to one cert. The only option I can think of is to change the DNS of my non-canonicalised domain to point at another server, install the second cert there, and then get that to redirect to my EC2 instance.

Comment: i'm on amazon too, i guess i could try the redirect... another server to manage & pay for though :-(

Comment: I have a wildcard cert and I still couldn't do it...until now! I've just realised I had host names specified in the bindings. I've cleared all host names and now it's working. Thanks for the help! :) PS. GeoTrust has reasonably cheap wildcard certs.